# How do I play a sound on Image-Click in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, playback

I'm trying to play a sound when i click or hover over my play button? Here's what i have so far. I have a button, if i hover over it it changes the Image, now i also want it to play an mp3.

```
play a {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:155px;
    height:134px;
    background-image:url(../images/Goodsound_PLAY_UP.png);
}
play a:hover {
    background-image:url(../images/Goodsound_PLAY_P.png);

I want to play a sound here

}
```

Im sorry for asking such an easy question. I'm an html noob, started last week.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/
http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/

Answer (score 3):

It's not that easy to play a sound in HTML. In fact, it wasn't until the html5 `audio` was there ! Even if html5 is not supported everywhere, it's now a little bit easier to play a sound in the browser.

My advice is to use [mediaelementJS](http://mediaelementjs.com/), a javascript library that fills the gap between old browser and html5 audio (and video) spec. Do not use the player (that comes with a full control bar), but use only the mediaelementjs component. To use it, simply include the library in the head of your page

```
<script src="js/libs/mediaelement.min.js"></script>
```

First, you have to put an audio tag in your html :

```
<audio id="mySound" src="my_audio_file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Then, call the Mediaelement library

```
var mySound = new MediaElement('mySound');
```

Finally, play it on your click or over event (here I use jQuery)

```
$('.play a').mouseover(function(){ mySound.play() });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

**JavaScript**

```
var audio = $("#audio");
$("play a").mouseenter( function() {
    audio.play();
}
```

where `audio` is an `<audio>` element, and `play a` is element which is hover.

Comment: JavaScript != jQuery, there's no jQuery in the tags nor mentioned anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using **jQuery**:

```
$("object_element_id") .on ('mouseover', function(e){
    // audio play code here
});

$("object_element_id") .on ('mouseout', function(e){
    // audio pause/stop code here
});
```

Why "*on*"? Just imagine a "AJAX page refresh". For remove it:

```
$("object_element_id") .off ('mouseenter');
```

Why "*mouseover*" and "*mouseout*"? Maybe you want to add extra functions for each status, like change IMG SRC of the button, make some effects... feel free. And why the "*e*" element? The E element is the object who fired the event - the image, the link etc. Do everything with it (or just remove it).

For audio play, you can use HTML5 tags. It's easy and are supported by the major browsers (you didn't asked "retrocompatibility") You can cache the element (like Mateusz' answer) and use it:

```
var $audio = $("#audio_element_id"); //for cache the element
$audio.setAttribute('src', url_link); //for change the URL file (ir can be MP3, OGG...)

$audio.play(); //for the mouseover
$audio.stop(); //for the mouseout
```

Then, the final code:

```
var $audio = $("audio_element"); //caching

$("object_element_id") .on ('mouseover', function(e){
    $audio.play();
});

$("object_element_id") .on ('mouseout', function(e){
    $audio.stop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also find this code useful (I think it is fairly modern, so it might not work with old browsers; I use it with Firefox 32).

```
<audio controls> <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> </audio>
```

There is a similar one for video, too:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="clip.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```

Comment: Information about those tags and about compatibility can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp and here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp