# how to make a button with sound and image (custom image)

Tags: html

I don't know how to make a button with a sound and custom image [here is what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOtkX.png)

Comment: Could you please share the code you have already tried?

Comment: Basically you can do this either changing the css for the button to include a background image or create a link out of an image. For the sound, you can attach event listener for the button and when it gets clicked, you play the sound file.

Comment: For the event listener you need a little bit of Javascript.

Comment: Try starting from the button with a custom image. Internet is full of examples for that. Same thing for the event listener. If you get stuck, come back here and update your question.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180581/how-do-i-play-a-sound-on-image-click-in-html

Comment: <h1>&nbsp &nbspNOPE<h1>
<iframe width="110" height="200" src="https://www.myinstants.com/instant/nope/embed/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: that is my code, sorry I haven't responded